# Wordpress 4.3 & Bootstrap 3.x - why do my containers overlap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

I am developing a theme in Wordpress that incorporates Bootstrap. My navbar, for some unknown reason, overlaps the text on my page at the top.  It is like the navbar is hovering over the webpage.

I have tried to add 'row' and specify a 12 width but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is the HTML for the navbar:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION
==================================================================== -->

<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">  
      <div class="container">

          <!-- left side of navbar -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-
                  toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BRAND</a>
          </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->

          <!-- right side of navbar -->
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li id="menu-item-216" class="menu-item menu-item-type-
post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-216"><a 
href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-205" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-203 current_page_item 
menu-item-205"><a href="http://www.example.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
object-page menu-item-219"><a href="http://www.example.com/faq/">FAQ</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-239" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
object-page menu-item-239"><a href="http://www.example.com/blog/">Blog</a>
</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div> <!-- end of container -->
    </nav> <!-- end of navbar -->
</div> <!-- end of navbar-wrapper -->
```

And the next part of the page is like below.  The navbar above actually overlaps the "About Us".

```
<div class="container">
     <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>A bunch of text goes here</p> 
</div>
```

Any assistance very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed it.  I want to keep the navbar-fixed-top.  To solve the above, I added the following to my css:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```